# Float type that implements `Eq` in rust

Tags: rust, floating-point, nan, equality-operator

In rust, is there a version of `f32` / `f64` that implements `Eq`?
The only reason I can see for `f32` / `f64` not implementing `Eq` is that `NaN != NaN`.
Potential ways such a type could behave:

1. The type could just make `NaN == NaN` for that type which would be really useful because I often assume that `a == a` is always true.
2. Another approach would be to disallow `NaN` entirely in that type so that there is no `NaN` that could be unequal to itself.

Ideally there would be a way to use that type just by using a suffix (similar to `2.3_f32`) but I don't think that is possible.

Comment: NaN isn't the only reason not to implement `Eq`. Comparing floating point numbers for equality is just not that useful in the first place: [`println!("{}", 0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3);`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b21fd293c03fd04b3dc4a9d76e46239e) prints `false` because of rounding errors and the decimal to binary conversions. Given that the `PartialEq` is already not that useful, it's not surprising no one would have bothered making a floating point type work with `Eq`.

Comment: [Rust internals forum: NonNan type discussion](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/pre-rfc-nonnan-type/8418/14). Its not trivial to avoid NaNs on computers whose instructions can produce NaN for even "simple" operations, and APIs designed to avoid that would either be fraught with panics or fallible results for the caller to handle. You can see if crates like [noisy-float](https://crates.io/crates/noisy_float) or [ordered-float](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float) suit your needs. You can of course make your own bespoke type wrapper that implements `Eq` with the specific behavior you desire.

Answer (score 3):

Since Rust 1.62.0, you can use the [`total_cmp()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#method.total_cmp) methods of `f32` and `f64`. Not a type on their own, but you can build a type on top of them if you want.

Or you can use the [`ordered-float`](https://crates.io/crates/ordered-float) crate. It provides the [`NotNan`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/struct.NotNan.html) and [`OrderedFloat`](https://docs.rs/ordered-float/latest/ordered_float/struct.OrderedFloat.html) types, each matching one behavior you described.